# Searching the Suppliers.xls file - Data quality Services tutorial

Tags: ssis, data-quality-services

I am trying to find the Suppliers.xls so I can finish this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tutorials/task-3-importing-domain-values-from-an-excel-file?view=sql-server-2014

I've searched everywhere and I couldn't find it so I thought maybe someone here could help me. Thank you.

I've looked on Microsoft docs, forum, google search...

Comment: at the left, the heading before lesson 1 called "Enterprise Information Management using SSIS, MDS, and DQS Together [Tutorial]" there is a prerequisites section in there that gives you the download link.

Comment: @TimMylott thank you for your reply. The link's description is " Suppliers.xls"  but the doc is a pdf, no tables... (However I'm not sure if we are talking about the same link)

Comment: Oh wow, my bad, sorry, I didn't click all the way through.  I see what you are talking about now.  Same link.  That file seems to have gone missing doing a quick search, others are looking for it as well.  Maybe someone did find it and will chime in.   Apologize for not looking closer before I commented.

Comment: That's ok @TimMylott ! I'll keep looking... =(

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the answer after about a year. But I believe it will be useful for someone else looking for this.

Go to https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-767-implementing-a-sql-data-ware-house-9781509306473

- Scroll below to the section 'Downloads' and download the zip file.
- The zip file has the suppliers.xlsx file.